# Custom views works with API21 but get ClassNotFound exception on lower APIs

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

When i run my app on android emulator with API21 it works fine, but when i run my app on API16 emulator, i catching error when my fragment inflating.
Error example

```
>  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ajax.ir.com.ajax/com.ir.ajax.activity.AuthentificationActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line **#57: Error inflating class com.ir.ajax.views.AJTextView**
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class com.ir.ajax.views.AJTextView . . . .
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ir.ajax.views.AJTextView
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at com.ir.ajax.fragments.AuthentificationFragment.onCreateView(AuthentificationFragment.java:26)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:434)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5095)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This view is in my fragment XML, that containing custom views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aj="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bttn_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="28dp"
    android:paddingTop="28dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/s_d_blue"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <!--<com.ir.ajax.views.AJButton
        android:id="@+id/bttn_enter"
        style="@style/ButtonBlueText"
        aj:typeface="os_light"
        android:text="@string/entry"
        android:onClick="onClick" />-->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bttn_enter"
        style="@style/ButtonBlueText"
        android:text="@string/entry"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/s_d_blue"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="28dp"
    android:paddingTop="28dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_500" />

    <com.ir.ajax.views.AJTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        aj:typeface="os_light"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@string/or"
        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_36" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_500" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/btnRegistration"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="28dp"
    android:paddingTop="28dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/s_d_blue"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <com.ir.ajax.views.AJButton
        android:id="@+id/bttn_register"
        style="@style/ButtonBlueText"
        aj:typeface="os_light"
        android:text="@string/registration"
        android:onClick="onClick" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/s_d_blue"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="all_fragments"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnActivitis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="all_activity"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

And fragment code:

```
    package com.ir.ajax.fragments;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.ir.ajax.R;
import com.ir.ajax.activity.AuthentificationActivity;

public class AuthentificationFragment extends Fragment {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

//TODO
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_authentication, null);

    Typeface os_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/os_light.ttf");
    Button bttn_enter = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bttn_enter);
    bttn_enter.setTypeface(os_light);

    //TODO
    final AuthentificationActivity owner = (AuthentificationActivity) getActivity();
    if (owner != null) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.btnMenu).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                owner.showDialog();
            }
        });
    }
    if (owner != null) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.btnActivitis).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                owner.showDialogActivities();
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}
```

}

Example of my custom view:

```
package com.ir.ajax.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ir.ajax.utils.TextViewUtils;

public class AJTextView extends TextView {

public AJTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
    TextViewUtils.initTypeface(this, context);
}

public AJTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        TextViewUtils.initTypeface(this, context, attrs);
    }
}

public AJTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        TextViewUtils.initTypeface(this, context, attrs);
    }
}

}
```

And my build file:

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 21
>     buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "ajax.ir.com.ajax"
>         minSdkVersion 16
>         targetSdkVersion 19
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>         multiDexEnabled = true
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>         debug {
>             debuggable true
>         }
>     }
>     compileOptions {
>         sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
>         targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
>     }
>     productFlavors {
>     }
>     lintOptions {
>         abortOnError false
>     }
> }
> allprojects {
>     gradle.projectsEvaluated {
>         tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
>             options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
>         }
>     }
> }
> dependencies {
>     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
>     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
>     compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
>     compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.3.jar')
>     compile project(':qrscanner')
>     compile files('libs/NettyClient-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
>     //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
>     compile files('libs/support-v4-22.0.0-javadoc.jar')
> }
> sonarRunner {
>     sonarProperties {
>         property "sonar.host.url", "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
>         property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar"
>         property "sonar.projectName", "Ajax"
>         property "sonar.language", "java"
>         property "sonar.sources", "src"
>         property "sonar.binaries", "build"
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has your project reached 65k+ methods (dex limit)? You seem to have enabled multidex in build.gradle. But doing so is not enough to support the multidex, you need to extend `MultidexApplication` in your Application class.

Android 5.0 and higher uses a runtime called ART which natively supports loading multiple dex files from application APK files. So that might be the reason why your app is working fine in API 5.0 +

```
public class YourApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

.

.
```

Also you need to specify dependency on multidex lib in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Have you done this?

For more info you can refer this doc
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: no, i didnt. maybe this is problem. cuz lolipop can handle dex limit withoun multidex. i'll try now

Comment: Yes! You was right! I have read that page for handling multi dex only till the moment when i was needed to set multiDexEnabled = true, and thought it was enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below, I don't sure, but it's can help.

```
public class AJTextView extends TextView {

public AJTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    TextViewUtils.initTypeface(this, context);
}

public AJTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        TextViewUtils.initTypeface(this, context, attrs);
    }
}

public AJTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    if (!isInEditMode()) {
        TextViewUtils.initTypeface(this, context, attrs);
    }
}

}
```

Also you can try use 19 api as target sdk compiler.

Comment: Nope, this didn't help